How to change locale of xfce4-terminal window?
I need to record a gif (using peek) of copy/paste for my project. But I want the interface to be English.

I was able to do this once, I've added
env LC_ALL=C exo-open --launch TerminalEmulator
in Launcher to change the locale of the terminal interface. But then I was not able to get it back to my normal locale UTF8.pl_PL. I was asking chatGPT and used this command:
exo-open --launch TerminalEmulator --command='unset LC_ALL && xfce4-terminal'

The command did not give any output but then I deleted the --command I get back my locale. But now I can't make it English again.
Running this in terminal
LC_ALL=C && xfce4-terminal

Doesn't work. I also tried:
localectl set-locale LC_MESSAGES=en_US.utf8
localectl set-locale LANG=en_US.utf8

But the interface is still in my default locale.
So how I should change the terminal interface locale to English and back to original locale (without rebooting)?
I use Fedora Xfce.

I was able to run terminal with sudo and change the locale:
sudo env LC_ALL=C xfce4-terminal

It will run new terminal window as root, but you can change the user with su command:
su - <username>


Why the sudo? Doesn't env LC_ALL=C xfce4-terminal work?

Don't use LC_ALL=C, it doesn't support any of the non-basic English letters. Use C.UTF-8 or en_US.UTF-8.

@egmont just env doesn't work, but running as a different user do work. Thanks for the tip about C.UTF-8 I was not able to use git log because of LC_ALL=C.
